# Need to fill the area of shapefile that contains LineStrings, which form a polygon, in ipython

Tags: polygon, area, linestring, fill, ipython

The porblem I have is that I fetched the data about the administrative level of vienna (from OSM via overpass --> vienna relation id = 109166) as **xml format**. (json didn't work it had encoding problems) As I did not find any information of how to get it directly, I had to see if I could create the filled polygon with the data provided. With the ways included, forming a polygon itself doesn't work as some ways only have two nodes. Therefore, I created LineStrings in order to generate the border of vienna and saved it as a shapefile.

It looks like this: [image]

Indicated by the different colors, one can see the LineStrings that form a polygon.
Now I would like to fill the area so that I can use it as a filled polygon. I am using **ipython** (with python 2.7) and currently searching for answers for the best approach to do this. Would be nice if there is a function that ipython can interpret all LineStrings and see that they are closed so it can write it as a polygon. Then I could identify it as polygon in order to fill the area. Working with programs like QGIS is not an option as I want to avoid manual corrections.

[Dropbox link for shapefile](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qzmq5hycrnmc7d7/AACv0MhPFPEzkvR7jgtTcNRHa?dl=0)

What I want is just a filled polygon of this relation in **ipython**.

Comment: Please **edit** your question to specify the GIS software you are using.

Comment: If I save the output from overpass-turbo.eu as geojSON for that ID I get a perfect polygon that fills nicely when loaded into QGIS. You're doing something wrong...

Comment: When trying to fetch the data in json I always encounter encoding problems in ipython, therefore, I did it in xml and created a shapefile with it afterwards.

Comment: @Spacedman How do you get geojson as output from overpass? If I try to do this I get an error. (e.g. http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:geojson];area(3600225494);(node(area)[%22amenity%22~%22theatre|cinema|arts_centre%22];);out%20body;) When changing "geojson" to "json" it works, but I have the problem of converting it to "geojson", which I did not find a solution for in python 2.7

Comment: I'm using overpass-turbo: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/kuS - run, then export as geoJSON.

Comment: I want to avoid using manual steps and do everythingin ipython, therefore, this is not an option for me as only following outputs are allowed: Error: line 1: static error: For the attribute "output" of the element "osm-script" the only allowed values are "xml", "json", "csv", "custom", or "popup".